# Terrain drawing with coordinates

Tags: three.js

I am trying to draw a terrain and I have some X,Y and elevation data, I use buffer geometry, basic material, to renderer the data, I can renderer each data a individual triangle, I don't no how to give index for this data. please can anyone guide me. **My data format look like image data.**

Comment: Here is a simple image to height field example which uses plane geometry and matches the vertices to a grey scale image: http://danni-three.blogspot.com/2013/09/threejs-heightmaps.html